# I have a button in an HBS file. how can I add a variable to the button that links to an external site?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

so I have a button on an hbs page. I need that button when clicked to send the user to an external link that is retrieved from a json response. I checked the handlebars docs but it doesn't have anything about inserting a variable/external link into an hbs button. when I use their code I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTsGo.png). that is technically the correct link but it doesn't work and also shouldn't look like. here's what I have so far which is mostly pulled from their [docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/contributing/button-links.html?#button-links). I have combed through their docs and have not been able to find anything directly relevant to this. I think I might have to make a helper or something but I wanted to get your thoughts before I went down that rabbithole

detail-page.hbs

```
<div>
     !button[INSTALL]({{marketplaceURL}})
</div>
```

the marketplace url is correctly grabbed in another file. and in the picture it displays the right link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use onclick on an "a" tag

```
<a onclick="window.location = 'https://google.com'">Google</button>
```

And style it accordingly.